# Join DEM and GPS data point ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have a problem using ArcGIS. I have generate a DEM raster with a 3D online software and exported it in ArcGIS. So I have a raster of my surface. After that, I have some GPS point `(x,y,z)` that we have take on the zone. To correct my DEM I want to replace my dem value by the point value where `DEM=point`. I have tried to use the raster calculator like this: `con(DEM=points,points,DEM)` but it gives me only the value of the points and not the DEM layer.

How can I integrate the points value to my DEM (I have the two in raster form)?

Comment: Try Con(IsNull(points), Dem, points)

Comment: Before you convert your points into a raster be sure to set your environment snapraster to the existing DEM or resampling will occur fuzzing the corrected value. I would think though that your ambition to rectify inaccuracies in your DEM is going to lead to an unusable product for contours, slope etc.. as only individual pixels are being changed, it would be far more useful to express your DEM as a terrain from your input, embed your points and export to a raster, although this will take longer and require a 3d analyst license your end product will be more useful.